# Touchpad too sensitive after updating from Debian 9 to Debian 10

Tags: debian, touchpad, xinput

I have recently upgraded my 2007 MacBook using [this tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/MacBook/2-1), which installs Debian 8.  I had successfully installed it, and was running Debian 8, but needed to change my trackpad speed beyond the system settings maximum (accessed with the settings GUI).  So I took to Google and found the marvellous `xinput`.  I ran `xinput list`, and a bunch of different items came up (there were about 20 from memory).  And they all had intuitive names.

I saw the one I wanted to change: `appletouch`.  So I ran `xinput --list-props appletouch` and I found the acceleration speed, which was set to 12.5 by default (I could not find a plain speed setting).  I changed it to 20 and didn't feel much difference (I was rebooting between changes as I wasn't sure if it would take effect immediately or not).  Then to 40, then to 60.  60 seems quite high, but it worked for what I needed, so I kept it as that.

Then I realised I could upgrade to Debian 9, so I did, and that was all fine.  Then I realised that I could upgrade again, to Debian 10, so I have done that.  However, now it really does feel like my touchpad acceleration is at 60, as I can keep my finger relatively still on the touchpad and it starts jittering around.  The only way it is usable is if I have my mouse speed on very low, or else there is no accuracy to where I am clicking.

So to fix this, I took to `xinput` again.  However, I could not find `appletouch` or anything of the like.  This was my output:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer            id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:15                   id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:15          id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard           id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:15                  id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

This isn't very intuitive anymore, and there are considerably fewer configuration options.  After having a look, it looks like 6 and 7 may be what I need to change.  However, I have changed these, and nothing has changed in terms of the feel of the trackpad.

The output when running `xinput --list-props 6` (which is the same output at 7) is (omitting quite a few decimal places)

```
Device Enabled (115): 1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (117): 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1
Device Accel Profile (240): 0
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (241): 1
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (242): 1
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (243): 10
```

What strikes me is that there is no option that feels like it is acceleration 60...  I can set `xinput --set-prop 6 231 1` and it will change, but when I reboot it is set back to normal (and at no point does anything feel different).

Help would be very much appreciated, as I don't know what to do to change this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Version 10 Debian uses *Wayland* so afaik you can't use `xinput`.
I never tried it but maybe [libinput](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/libinput/) helps in this regard.

---

> I found the acceleration speed, which was set to 12.5 by default (I could not find a plain speed setting)

You can also change the speed by modifying the transformation matrix:

```
xinput set-prop <your-device-id> "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0.3 0 0 0 0.3 0 0 0 1
```

Also if the pointer is jittery try to set "Noise cancelling" to a higher value if your driver supports this property.

To retain changes made by `xinput` after restart put the commands into `.xsessionrc` in your home dir. Create the file if necessary.